# Powershell Get-EventLog output issue when logging

Tags: powershell, get-eventlog

I am having an issue with the writing of a get-eventlog function when I'm writing to a TXT file.

**This is my LogWrite function:**

```
#Log Function
$Logfile = "..\Logs\$(gc env:computername)_Outlook.log"
$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")

Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)
   Add-content $Logfile -value $Stamp": "$logstring -Force
}
```

This is my LogWrite code in part of my script.

```
$OutlookHangDetailed = Get-EventLog -Log "Application" -Source "Application Hang" -Message "*OUTLOOK.EXE*" -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-12) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

LogWrite $OutlookHangDetailed | Format-List
```

The issue I am having is its coming out like this in the txt file:
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo

But if I simply echo it, it comes out like this (This is an example):

```
Index              : 2568
EntryType          : Information
InstanceId         : 15
Message            : Updated Symantec Endpoint Protection status successfully to SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON.
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
ReplacementStrings : {Symantec Endpoint Protection, SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON}
Source             : SecurityCenter
TimeGenerated      : 3/15/2017 7:46:02 AM
TimeWritten        : 3/15/2017 7:46:02 AM
```

How can I get this to write to the log this way?

Comment: It seems to only happen when using Add-Content. Any reason as to why?

Answer (score 1):

- There is no output from your log function. You are not piping anything into `Format-List`
- `$OutlookHangDetailed` is going to be an array of objects of `[System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry]`. You can turn it into a string with `$logstring | fl | out-string`. Casting directly to a string isn't going to give you the output you are looking for.

---

```
$Logfile = "..\Logs\$(gc env:computername)_Outlook.log"
$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")

Function LogWrite {
        Param (
            [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry[]]$logstring,
            [string]$Logfile,
            [string]$Stamp
        )


        $logentry = "$($Stamp):$($logstring | fl | out-string)"
        Add-Content $Logfile -value $logentry -Force
        $logentry
    }

$OutlookHangDetailed = Get-EventLog -Log "Application" -Source "Application Hang" -Message "*OUTLOOK.EXE*" -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-12) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

LogWrite $OutlookHangDetailed $Logfile $Stamp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-EventLog -Log "Application" -Source "Application Hang" -Message "*OUTLOOK.EXE*" -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-12) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue >> "..\Logs\$(gc env:computername)_Outlook.log"
```

This will work as expected

Comment: This works, partially. I am trying to format it like this using Format-List

Index              : 2568
EntryType          : Information
InstanceId         : 15
Message            : Updated Symantec Endpoint Protection status point Protection, SECURITY_PRODUCT_STATE_ON}
Source             : SecurityCenter
TimeGenerated      : 3/15/2017 7:46:02 AM
TimeWritten        : 3/15/2017 7:46:02 AM

But it comes out like this:

l y   t o   S E C U R I T Y _ P R O D U C T _ S T A T E _ O N .

Comment: I'd like for it to come out how I have it above when i Echo it, but it doesn't with the command you provided, it seems like it isn't formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
    Function LogWrite
    {
       param (
         $logstring
       )

       $Stamp | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath $Logfile -Append -Force
       ($logstring | Format-List) | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath $Logfile -Width 1024 -Append -Force
    }
```

And call your function with:

```
    LogWrite $OutlookHangDetailed
```